# Integration with xero practice manager

Tags: xero-api

Is there a way to integrate a third-party application with Xero Practice Manager for Tax Returns?

I do not see an API endpoint for that. I want to be able to query clients and retrieve their tax information/statuses through an API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at theWorkFlowMax API (same one used for Xero Practice Manager)

https://www.workflowmax.com/api/overview

These are the only endpoints available at this time.